# Hide and view back a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm opening second form from my main form like this.
On a combo box selected index changed event.

Code in main form.

```
      if (cmbVtMgmnt.SelectedItem.ToString()=="Basic Voter Management")
        {
            this.Visible = false;
            frmVoterOP votefrm = new frmVoterOP();
            votefrm.Show();
        }
```

How can I view the main form or open main form from the second form's label click event.

```
    private void lblBacktoMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //What should come here?
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass main form object to your frmVoterOP form and use that object to show or hide the main form

*In main form*

```
frmVoterOP votefrm = new frmVoterOP(this);
```

*In frmVoterOP*

```
MainForm frmMainForm; 
public frmVoterOP(MainForm mainForm)
{
    frmMainForm = mainForm;
}
```

*To show the main form from frmVoterOP*

```
private void lblBacktoMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmMainForm.Show(); 
}
```

**Another alternative** could be using the [Form.Owner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the second form.

*In main form*

```
if (cmbVtMgmnt.SelectedItem.ToString()=="Basic Voter Management")
{
    this.Visible = false;
    frmVoterOP votefrm = new frmVoterOP() {Owner = this};
    votefrm.Show();
}
```

In frmVoterOP

```
private void lblBacktoMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MainForm mainForm = (MainForm)this.Owner;
     mainForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: can you show how to open main form from VoterOP form?

Comment: This line "frmVoterOP votefrm = new frmVoterOP(this);" gives me an error saying, The best overload method match for frmVoterOP(Mainform) has some invalid arguments.

Comment: You have to use your form name instead of MainForm in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you can also use `ShowDialog()`:

```
if (cmbVtMgmnt.SelectedItem.ToString()=="Basic Voter Management")
{
    this.Visible = false;
    frmVoterOP votefrm = new frmVoterOP();
    votefrm.ShowDialog();
    this.Visible = true;
}
```

So now when the `votefrm` is closed, your main form should pop back up.